# meteor. How to display values?

Tags: meteor

Please anybody help me. I want to display values in meteor js like this code in sql "select * from table where status='available' and (category='notebook' or category='LCD') ". Please show me the best solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = SomeCollection.find({
  status: 'available',
  category: { $in: ['notebook', 'LCD'] },
}).fetch();
```

Comment: do i need to put this coding in server or client?

Comment: Are you running this query to display the values to a user? If so, I'd imagine you'd publish the `SomeCollection` documents to the client and then run the above in a helper. I really can't add more without knowing your exact use case.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).